# unable to access cifs network shared drive via fstab entry despite having administrator rights

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, cifs

Good afternoon-
I am new to Linux and am attempting to mount a network shared drive with fstab entry but continue to receive a dialog stating "only system administrators have the permission to do this."  My apologies if my nomenclature is unclear, let me know and I can elaborate as best I can understand.  Below is the fstab entry:

```
//192.168.1.3/Public  /home/media/MyBook1 cifs auto,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,credentials=/root/.cifscredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I have added administrative rights to the user profile via "users and groups" as well as the terminal.  Mounts fine with `sudo mount -a` from terminal.  Have tried the fstab entry with and without: `dir_mode,file_mode,uid,gid,sec=ntlm`.  Created the directory locally without using sudo if it makes a difference.

Running Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: Is your problem that it won't mount at boot?

Comment: The issue was that it would not mount unless going through terminal using sudo access

Answer (score 0):

I can't specifically answer the question of why your code is not working. Below is the line in my fstab file, which mounts a shared drive when the computer boots. Modify for your situation and see if it works.

```
#Mount Western Digital Passport Drive On Router  - Not part of Logical Volume Management (LVM)
//rt-n56u/sda1 /media/My_Passport cifs file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,rw,guest,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,forceuid,gid=34,forcegid,nofail 0      0
```

Ubuntu documentation: [fstab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/fstab.5.html)

ArchLinux documentation: [fstab](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/fstab#External_devices)

PS: I noticed after posting that your **uid** and **gid** both use the same number. The effect of using the same number for your **uid** or **gid** is unknown to me.

Comment: After much process of trial and error removing different mount options, it was "auto" that was causing the problem.                                     In response to your question regarding the uid and gid being the same number, that is the case in my setup, don't know if that is typical.  Head to terminal and type "id" and it will spit out all the numeric identifiers.

Comment: Yes its normal in that the first user created on a Linux system will be in the first user group. Uid and gid values below 1000 are typically for system accounts.